# Original order in isotope is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, frontend, masonry

I am trying to fix the "Original order" but it is not working, i even tried to make it like "[(i based my code here)](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/qxT6F/)", but it didn't work.

Here is my code: [Isotope Original order](http://jsfiddle.net/geobarney/vk44h2dm/19/)

My intent is to make a ascending, descending, and back to normal or original position of the boxes which i think is not working. i tried to research on the internet and i found some but the problem is, it is not working on my code.

Can you take a look on my code and give me advice how to solve it? thank you.

Jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){

//Configure
var $container = $('#item-container');

$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },

    getSortData : {  
          name : function ( $elem ) {
            return $elem.find('.name').text();
          }  
    },

});


//Sorting
$('#sorts li a').click(function(){
        $('#sorts li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-sort');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
         });
         return false;
}); 

//Ascending
$('.sorting_a-z').on( 'click', function( event ) {

    $container.isotope({ 
        itemSelector : '.item',
         sortBy: 'name', sortAscending : true
    }); 

});

//Descending
$('.sorting_z-a').on( 'click', function( event ) {

    $container.isotope({ 
        itemSelector : '.item',
         sortBy: 'name', sortAscending : false
    }); 

});


//Put on original Position
$('.all_items').on( 'click', function( event ) {

     $container.isotope({ 
        itemSelector : '.item',
        filter: filterValue
     }); 
    return false;
});});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to manage how to put back in original order.

Here i my code.

[fixed code for orginal order](http://jsfiddle.net/geobarney/2239gk1t/2/)

Jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){

//Configure
var $container = $('#item-container');

$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },

    getSortData : {  
          name : function ( $elem ) {
            return $elem.find('.name').text();
          }  
    },

});


//Sorting
$('#sorts li a').click(function(){
        $('#sorts li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-sort');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
         });
         return false;
}); 

//Ascending
$('.sorting_a-z').on( 'click', function( event ) {

    $container.isotope({ 
        itemSelector : '.item',
         sortBy: 'name', sortAscending : true
    }); 

});

//Descending
$('.sorting_z-a').on( 'click', function( event ) {

    $container.isotope({ 
        itemSelector : '.item',
         sortBy: 'name', sortAscending : false
    }); 

});});
```